# Limit $\lim_{T \to \infty} \sin(T \cdot x)/T$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How would you calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{T \to \infty}  \frac{\sin(T \cdot x)}{T}=?$$
What I have tried so far is to write $\sin(\cdot)$ as a Taylor series. However, this technique didn't work. What other tests might be useful in this case?

Comment: Notice $|\sin (Tx)/T|\le 1/|T|$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Remmember that $-1\le\sin(Tx)\le1$ and then

$$-\frac{1}{T}\le \frac{\sin(Tx)}{T}\le\frac{1}{T}$$

Now think about *Squeeze theorem*.

Answer (score 0):

We know that sine function revolves around the value of +1 and -1.

$$\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sin (Tx)}{T}=0$$

Why? Sin can only revolve around +1 and -1.

$$\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{T}=0$$